# Chrome Developer Tools: difference between Size and Content

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Chrome Dev Tools - “Size” vs “Content”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072921/chrome-dev-tools-size-vs-content)

What is the difference between size and content info in the chrome developer tools network tab? Is it about compression?

example:
http://blogs.adobe.com/edge/files/2012/01/chrome_network_404.png

thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe size represents what was transferred over the network (including http headers) and content represents the total size of the content.

For example, if I hit a page that responds with 304 not modified the size is only a few bites while the content is much greater as only the header with the 304 response was sent over the network.

Also, size could be smaller if the content was zipped before it was sent over the network.