# Chrome Devs tools - where's size and content?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

According to [Chrome Dev Tools - "Size" vs "Content"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072921/chrome-dev-tools-size-vs-content), I should be able to see Size (bytes on the wire) and Content (uncompressed size).

I remember seeing this at one time.

But now (Chrome 38), I only see one measurement, and I'm not sure which one it is.

[image]

Can I see the compressed and uncompressed sizes with the Chrome Dev Tools?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You should press `Big resource rows` to see more data.

[image]

Comment: Really helped me !

Answer (score 24):

If you are using the latest version of Chrome (like 78+), you can check "Use large request rows" under the settings icon.

Doc: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/reference/#uncompressed

[image: Chrome DevTools screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck because only the name of the file was showing up (no other columns), but I realized that you must close the "details" view that shows on the right side when you click a row to see any other columns. Posting the answer here since search brought me here, though it wasn't the OP's actual issue.