# Why size of script file in browser is less than original file size

Tags: file, optimization, browser, kendo-ui

In my application i am using many script files. Some of them are from Kendo. One of the script file is originally 7.1 mb but when I check it in browser's network tab it shows it as 1.6mb.
Another file Kendo.all.min is originally of 2.5 mb but browser shows it as 1001 kb.
How the file size is different.
Bdw, I am working on website optimization.

[image]

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072921/chrome-dev-tools-size-vs-content