# Apache GZip compresion using mod_deflate

Tags: apache, .htaccess, webserver, gzip, mod-deflate

I was trying to configure mod_deflate for compression in Apache 2.2  and did following changes in httpd.conf file.

```
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript
```

Moreover i did change log level to `LogLevel debug` so i can verify the changes,
And its printing below compresion logs as well in error.log file however Chrome is still showing old size rather than compressed size in network tab of developer  tool.

Can anyone help me understand what going wrong here.Thanks in Advance.

**error.log**

```
[debug] mod_deflate.c(710): [client ::1] Zlib: Compressed 272070 to 68607 : URL /test.js, referer: http://localhost/
    [debug] mod_deflate.c(710): [client ::1] Zlib: Compressed 4286 to 681 : URL /dummy.ico, referer: http://localhost/
```

And in access log also i can see compressed size which is close to 68607 but browser still showing 272070 
**access.log**

```
"GET /test.js HTTP/1.1" 200 68625
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome Dev Tools - "Size" vs "Content"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072921/chrome-dev-tools-size-vs-content)

Comment: @Joe Thanks for reply. i checked that link already and its showing same data(means in KBs) for Size and Content